# Where in the yaml do I set "HostNetwork: true"?

Tags: kubernetes, bind9

I found one post that suggested I use

```
HostNetwork: true
```

in the spec: section on my bind9-deployment.yaml file but I'm not sure whether it goes in the spec: under

```
kind: Service
```

or

```
kind: Deployment
```

section of my file.

I am hoping eventually to make my on-prem bind9 service available to my local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy) for more info about DNS policy when using hostNetwork.

```
version: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      container:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for this, gohm'c. Now I need to figure out how to get these pods "behind" a single, static IP.